How can I improve my YouTube playlist querying program to handle more than 100 videos?
I have a C# program designed to retrieve all video titles from a public YouTube playlist. However, my current implementation only retrieves the first 100 videos due to the way YouTube dynamically loads additional content.
And if you have an idea of a more professional way, I would be happy to consider it.
static async Task<List<string>> GetAllVideos(string id)
{
    string url = $"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={id}";

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        string html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, "\"title\":{\"runs\":\\[{\"text\":\"(.*?)\"\\}");

        return matches.Take(matches.Count - 8)
            .Select(x => Regex.Unescape(x.Groups[1].Value)).ToList();
    }
}


How to use the YouTube API to extract video titles and next page token? (C# code at the bottom) -- WebView2 player, in case it's needed: How do I get YouTube native player to allow full screen in WebView2?

Yeah, don't do page scraping. It's fragile and gives you issues like you are seeing. It is also super vulnerable to Google changing their layout and breaking your app. This is why we have well documented APIs, as mentioned in the previous comment.

I did use the api, and i had a problem with that. if a video is not available, the api still shows it. But i just want to get the currently available videos. The only way i find is this workaround. it will be good for me.
